# Grey Volume bar - coreaudiod - Job failed to exec(3) for weird reason: 2

Tags: macos, audio, launchd, sound-volume

I've just installed the Mavericks 10.9.1 update and my audio is not working. The volume bar is obscurely grey, and the mac is becoming slightly slow.

I checked the console to see anything related to this issue and I found this message every ten seconds.

```
Dec 22 08:07:33 hko com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.audio.coreaudiod[989]): Job failed to exec(3) for weird reason: 2
Dec 22 08:07:33 hko com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.audio.coreaudiod): Job should be able to exec(3) now.
Dec 22 08:07:33 hko com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.audio.coreaudiod): Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
```

I've searched on google for this issue and no luck.

I'm not sure if this has got to do with my mac's permissions but I'm not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 2):

"Weird reason 2" is `ENOENT`: No such file or directory. The file the job is referring to (`/usr/bin/sandbox-exec` on my installation) no longer exists.

Answer (score -1):

In my bash script I made every path absolute. That was not enough!

Im my LaunchAgent I made use of **~** in stead of **/Users/xyz**.

This fixed the issue for me.